# jQuery - Divide width of the wrapper to the number of div`s inside

Tags: jquery, css

I need some help. I have a div wrapper and some other div's inside that will be added dynamically. The number of div's inside will be random so I need a script that will know how many div's are inside and which will be the width of the div's to fit in the wrapper perfectly.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="block">A1</div>
<div class="block">A2</div>
<div class="block">A3</div>
<div class="block">A4</div>
<div class="block">An</div>
</div>
<style>
#wrapper {width:1000px;}
div.block {margin:0 0 20px 20px; border:1px solid #ccc;}
</style>
```

If you can consider the margins and border will be great!
Thank you!

This is my script. It`s good, but not good handling the margins.

```
var ct = $('#wrapper').children().size();
var dw = $('#map').width() / (ct) - 25;
$("div.block").width(dw);
```

Thanks to the answers below I made the script work! 
Thank you all!

Comment: It's no problem, I just fixed it to make it a bit easier for others to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UTaSg/

You might have some extra space left because I round the decimal extra space down.

The script can easily be improved by adding the extra space left of the decimals the the first or last element.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, given that I've understood you correctly and each "div.block" has the same width:

```
var $blocks = $('#wrapper .block');
$('#wrapper').css('width', $blocks.length * $blocks.first().width(true));
```